# How to keep the vertical alignment of a list consistent?

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I have a list on my website in a 600px `div` and the text wraps, so the text on one of the lines drops down. This is fine but the problem I'm having is that the new line that has dropped down starts from the same place as the "points" and not where the text is.

Here's the problem I'm getting when it's viewed in a browser:

[image]

The problem isn't there in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7u5aN/)

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>Global access 24 hours a day, 365 days a year to specialised Cisco engineers</li>
  <li>Option for next business day hardware replacement (where available)</li>
  <li>Ongoing operating system software updates, including both minor and major releases within your licensed feature set</li>
  <li>Proactive diagnostics and real-time alerts on select devices</li>
</ul>
```

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh! I got it. I did have another style over-riding it:

```
ul, li, ol {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

I removed this and it works fine.

Comment: I told you. So you didn't even check if the issue exists in your JSFiddle example.

Comment: It's because in JSFiddle I chose only the code that I needed. But in my main CSS file I had that extra piece of code from a previous webpage I had copied chunk of code from. Just forgot that it was in there.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, that you didn't check if example is appropriate.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use style below:

```
.list {
    margin-left:20px;
    list-style-position:outside;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7u5aN/1/

And a padding/margin if needed.

By the way, I can see that it is by default in both Chrome and FF.

Comment: Have you debugged it in Firebug? Because even in your JSFiddle example is it fine without mine advice. Maybe some other style rule is overriding this.

Comment: In which browser the issue appears? Does it appear in this JSFiddle too?

Comment: happens in the latest version of chrome and also IE10

Answer (score 0):

It  depends on the user's browser. Your Fiddle works fine in chrome.

try this.

```
.list li {

        text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: i think any other style is overriding that one. can you check in the developer tool of Chrome ?

Comment: Sorry, how do I go about doing that? not something I've had to do before.

Comment: browse that in Chrome, then press CTRL + SHIFT + I to open the developer tool. Now click on the icon   shown as a lense to select your element then click that element in the html.
Now you can see  all the styles in the right hand side panel.